# Returning category id from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using the below query to return all "active" entries from the "place" table. Each author can also be included in a category (cat_id) and I would also like to return that for sorting purposes. $user_id represents the logged in user's id and cat_id should only be returned where userid = $user_id. I tried a few things but can't seem to get it working. The below query is working, but if a user is in multiple categories, it's returning the entry twice.

```
$active = 1;
$query_str = "SELECT a.*,b.user_id,c.username,c.fbook, d.cat_id FROM place a
LEFT OUTER JOIN wait b ON a.id=b.post_id AND b.user_id='$user_id'
JOIN users c ON a.userid=c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_cat d ON d.userid='$user_id' AND d.user_id=a.userid
WHERE ACTIVE = ? ORDER BY a.date desc";
$q = $this->db->query($query_str, $active);
```

user_cat table

```
+-----+--------+--------+---------+-----------------+
| id  | userid | cat_id | user_id | fbid            |
+-----+--------+--------+---------+-----------------+
| 295 |    268 |     52 |     277 | 100001077604247 | 
| 296 |    268 |     52 |     271 | 100000021742637 | 
| 297 |    268 |     53 |     276 |               0 | 
| 298 |    268 |     53 |     272 | 100000038821713 | 
| 299 |    268 |     53 |     275 |               0 | 
+-----+--------+--------+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: How do I return cat_id for each of the entries if the user is included in a category?

Comment: put the structure of your table and tell us clearly what you really want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the join on user_cat table to

```
LEFT JOIN (select userid, cat_id from user_cat group by user_id) AS d ON d.userid='$user_id' AND d.user_id=a.userid
```

this may help

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (select userid, GROUP_CONCAT(cat_id) AS cat_id, user_id from user_cat group by user_id) AS d ON d.userid='$user_id' AND d.user_id=a.userid`
I did it like this and it's exactly what I need.

Comment: glad it helps you, just wana share one thing that according to my knowledge GROUP_CONCAT has a limit of 1024 characters; no idea if it can be extended or not. so if your data exceed from it it will trim it.